# Is fstrim only for SSD?

Tags: boot, hard-drive

my system was taking a really long time to boot. I discovered that through "systemd-analyze blame" I could find out what was causing all that delay.

It was fstrim.service. Researching about it, it seems to me that this service is only for SSD, which I don't have in my computer, I have only one 500GB HDD.

So I just disabled the start up of this service, and things seem to be a lot better.

Did I do the right thing? Is fstrim important for an HDD also?